# HI, I want to visualise a specific row plot for all columns in a dataframe using plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

In the dataframe attached, I want to plot **all the columns(fat, saturates, sugars, salt and cal)** for  **diet_coke**  against **date as the x axis for all the dates** using plotly barchart function.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gj8p.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add your best-effort code? And some test data in text or code form?  What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please refer to the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-charts-with-wide-format-data) for examples of data frame wide format.